# How I can use AvRoutekit player for share audio from from WatchKit to connected bluetooth devices

Tags: swift, objective-c, watchkit, watch, watchos

I am using AVPlayer for play audios which use watch speaker for play sound on watch. But I want show airplay button like Apple Music app do. I am attaching image I need functionality like this button.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ooxci.jpg)

Comment: AvRoutekit?  Where does it come from?

Comment: I am just trying to implement native music airplay functionality in my own music application but there is not much documentation available for airplay audio from watch to connected bluetooth devices even its not opening bluetooth settings from my watch app I am not able to find that also

Comment: @ElTomato AVRoutekit Not available for watchOS